# No overload matches this call with styled components (index.d.ts(2187, 9))

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am trying to create Input component using styled components that takes props. When I try the prop called onChange get the error No overload matches this call.
I think my types aren't correct for something but after googling hours upon hours I have still not come to an answer.
What am I missing?

```js
interface Input {
  onChange?: (x? : string ) => void,
  disabled?: boolean,
  readonly?: boolean,
  width?: CSSUnit,
  heightlightColor?: string,
  bgColor?: string,
  type?: string,
  placeholder?: string,
  isFocus?: boolean,
  fontSize?: CSSUnit,
  highlightColor?: string,
  padding? : CSSUnit,
  height? : CSSUnit
}

const InputWrapperDefault = styled.input<Input>`
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: ${(props) => props.fontSize || '16px' };
  padding: ${(props => props.padding ? props.padding : '16px')};
  box-sizing: border-box;
`

const Input: React.FC<Input> = (props) => {
  const [isFocus, setFocus] = useState(false);
  const {
    highlightColor,
    onChange = ()=>{},
    type = 'text',
    width,
    bgColor,
    ...restProps
  } = props;
  console.log(isFocus);
  return (
        <InputWrapperDefault
          autoCapitalize="sentences"
          autoComplete="on"
          autoCorrect="on"
          dir="auto"
          maxLength={50}
          name='name'
          onChange={(e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>):void => { onChange(e.target.value)} }
          onClick={()=> setFocus(true)}
          spellCheck="true"
          type={type}
          {...restProps}
        />
  )
}
```

```
(JSX attribute) onChange?: (React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> & ((x?: string | undefined) => void)) | undefined
```

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Omit<Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>, "key" | keyof InputHTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; } & Input, never> & Partial<...>, "theme"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> & ((x?: string | undefined) => void)'.
      Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(x?: string | undefined) => void'.
        Types of parameters 'e' and 'x' are incompatible.
          Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"input", any, Input, never, "input", "input">): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"input", any, Input, never, "input", "input">, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>', gave the following error.
    Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> & ((x?: string | undefined) => void)'.
      Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(x?: string | undefined) => void'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(2187, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>, "key" | keyof InputHTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; } & Input, never> & Partial<...>, "theme"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'
index.d.ts(2187, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>, "key" | keyof InputHTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; } & Input, never> & Partial<...>, "theme"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'
```

[image]

Updated on `onChange?: (x? : string ) => void,`

Answer (score 1):

The crux of the error is this: `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.` That is to say, in your `Input` type you specify that the argument to `onChange` might be `undefined` (because of the optional `?`) or `string` instead of a `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`, but you then try to assign a handler to `onChange` that only accepts a `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` instead of any of the three possibilities.

If I'm understanding what you're accomplishing with the string vs. event type and the unwrapping to `e.target.value`, you ought to get the desired result by changing the two `onChange` lines to this:

```
onChange?: (x: string | ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void,
```

and this:

```
onChange={(e: string | ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>):void => { onChange((typeof e === 'string') ? e : e.target.value)} }
```

Here I've done away with the `undefined` branch entirely, assuming that the method won't be called without any argument. I've then arranged for the handler to accept a `string` by passing it through unchanged.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. But I am confused about the 
`onChange={(e: string | ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>):void => { onChange((typeof e === 'string') ? e : e.target.value)} }`

I think the e is always equal to` ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` not string, isn't it?

Comment: The `onChange` handler where the error occurred is being passed to an `InputWrapperDefault`, which is in turn a `styled.div` version of your `Input` type, where `onChange` is defined as being `string | ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`. The argument type passes through to what your handler must handle. (It looks like you've edited the code a bit, but I'm referring to the original code above.)

Comment: Sorry, I got mistake. @kdau